# Why hopping amplitude with no negative sign?

Tags: topological-insulators, tight-binding

I'm learning SSH model now.
I notice people use tight-binding model of this form,

$$H=t\sum_{<i,j>} c_i^†c_j+\mathrm{H.c}$$

where $t>0$ in [Lecture 1 : 1-d SSH model](https://phyx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TI/Lecture%20notes/1.html), or [A Short Course on
Topological Insulators](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295).
However, normally, hamiltonian is

$$H=-t\sum_{<i,j>} c_i^†c_j+\mathrm{H.c}$$
where $t>0$ means electrons can stay in both sites lowering their kinetic energy.

What is the meaning of $t>0$ or $t=0$ in the first notation?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $t=0$ kills the hopping entirely, so that would mean a chain with zero kinetic term.

The precise convention for a hopping term in the tight-binding regime depends on your conventions and how you want to "transcribe" the kinetic term from the continuum version which is $\frac{p^2}{2m}$ (or $-\Delta\equiv-\partial_i\partial^i$ in natural units). The important point in the continuum is that the $-\Delta$ has positive spectrum, so that the kinetic term is a positive, but more importantly, bounded from below operator. Hence, the sign is absolutely important.

In the tight-binding regime, conversely, any version of the discrete Laplacian you would take would be bounded from below *and above* and hence it actually doesn't matter which sign you pick. Indeed usually the discrete Laplacian is normalized so that its spectrum is symmetric about zero (as is also the case in the SSH model) and so there is no meaning for the sign of $t$.